# codemirror - mark selection remembers previous marks

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I have a dynamic text marker which can mark one part of text at first, but then I want to make this part of text to be unmarked and mark another part of text. I'm using this code for marking my text:

```
editor.markText({line: 0, ch: inp}, {line: 0, ch: inp+1}, {className:  "styled-background"});
```

-if I clear all of the marks with clear() function, it will clear it (or I was also trying to remove all of the classes "styled-background"), but always when I call the method above again it will mark what I want to mark, but also all of the previous marks !

here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zctfLuww/1/) - the problem might be I'm creating textarea dynamically, but all of the id's and classes in this div looks fine. Type a number into the input and it will mark the char on required position, 5 is default, try to type 8 and there will be marked chars at 5 and 8 index instead of just 8. (zero is not working but it does not matter).

Comment: Could you set up a demo that shows this behavior? (On http://jsbin.com, for example).

Comment: jsfiddle demo updated.

Comment: You are never clearing the markers you're creating there (only a bogus one that you seem to create only to clear it).

Comment: If it helps to make the answer clearer I've created a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/y9drt2b3 that shows the same marker being cleared as created.